# Cron Job for laravel web application

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this laravel web application installed on a Dreamhost server. At the admin end I was given this line of code at the beginning

Please Set Cron Job Now
To automate the return interest, we need to set the cron job and make sure the cron job is running properly. Set the Cron time as minimum as possible. Once per 5-15 minutes is ideal while once every minute is the best option.

curl -s https://capitalmaxoptions.com/cron

How do I go about this? Does it go into the kernel.php file?

Comment: You can all find in documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have the job in `kernel.php` file.

Best option is to make a command for your cron job so you don't mix the specific job with the others. You can check [about Making Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands).

Inside your `handle` function you may have your execution

```php
public function handle()
{
   // cURL request or your backend function to your logic
}
```

Next is to schedule the frequency of the command which (5-15 minutes) in you case. You can check [about the Frequency Options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options).In your `kernel.php` file, inside the schedule function you can call your function and set the frequency.

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // If your command is cron:interest
    $schedule->command('cron:interest')->->everyFifteenMinutes();     
}
```

You can test your command by starting the scheduler manually on localhost. Check the [Run Task Scheduler](http://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) link shared in the comments @Autista_z shared to configure scheduler.